# Apache / PHP is serving the wrong content type

Tags: php, apache2, http-headers, content-type

I have this PHP file:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="hello world example" /> 
  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[ 
       Hello, world!
     ]]>
  </Content> 
</Module>
```

I would expect it to return a `Content-type:text/xml` header.

What it does however is to return `Content-Type:text/html`

You can have a look at the result over here: http://knox.orgapage.de/hello.php

If I change the file extention to .xml (without the PHP tags of course), everything works fine. I however want to generate the content dynamicaly with PHP.

Any suggestions how to solve this? How can I let the browser know, that it should interpret the content as XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it does not output any text as well.
I assume it is because of some error on the PHP side
You have to refer to error log and repair that error.

yeah that's it

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
?>

<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="hello world example" /> 
  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[ 
       Hello, world!
     ]]>
  </Content> 
</Module>
```

will solve your problem